# SSH login script before login

Tags: 14.04, server

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to execute a script during an ssh connection at the time the banner `/etc/issue` or `issue.net` is displayed? I know about `motd`, but it is executed AFTER login. I would like to execute my script before the login.
2. The file `issue.net` is not parsed for security reasons (to avoid an attack from the server to the client). This means that I can't put escape sequences inside to clear the screen, color the text. I can't even display japanese text. How can I disable this behavior?

I have spent a long time searching for those two answers. Some pages describe a few escape sequences to work with agetty, but my ubuntu server 14.04 seems to use getty instead.

I have also explored the PAM modules… without any luck so far.